Using grid for layout maximization in PAEG, grid cannot adapt to size
I have a form, and I have a Frame inside the form
A page is assigned to the Frame of the form and its effect is
enter image description here
When I maximize the form it does
enter image description here
I won't show it because it's mostly styling code
Windows
  <Grid>
      <Frame x:Name="Region"   Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
  </Grid>

Page
    <Grid  Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}"  x:Name="PagePanle" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0"   BorderThickness="0,1,0,2" Background="{DynamicResource LoginBrush}"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MoudlePanle">
        <ListBox Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}"   BorderThickness="0"  x:Name="MenusListBox" 
                     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 Padding="-2" />
    
    </Grid>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource FontBrush}"  BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" Background="{DynamicResource LoginBrush}"/>
</Grid>

The interface has a page in which I used Grid for layout and divided them into three parts, where part 1 and part 3 are absolute height and part 2 is the remaining space. But I was surprised by how well it worked; So give the second part a background color at this point I understand that the second part does not fill all the remaining space, I want to implement what should I do
I tried to set two parts of Grid.RowSpan="3" and set the height of the two parts to auto, but it did not achieve the effect I wanted
I hope to get your reply, which will make me very grateful

I used an animation in the grid.row =2 layout and the animation set the height value so that the Grid did not adapt. This part of the code did not show up in the code content. This is a bad question
